# Loop over cards in the UI

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there someone who can tell me how you loop over the contacts in the template "Vendor ratings" please ?

I give you a screenshot of the page. To reproduce, go to the "Contacts" page, add a new contact and see two contacts...

I want to do the same behavior for my application and I don't know how to loop...

When I create a single card with a label binding @datasource.item.name for example, I only have 1 card displayed although in my datasource I have two results...

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: Screenshot contacts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for widgets that can render repetitive data: [List](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/layout-widgets#list), [Accordion](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/layout-widgets#accordion), [Grid](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/layout-widgets#grid). You can build prototype row/cell inside such widget, bind it to array of items (datasource) and App Maker's runtime will take care about the rest for you:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavel.